# Whats stopping my jquery function from executing ajax script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

> i have a jquery function which gets the two values one for school/college and one for state and sends it to the controller class under the url "Type&State" but for some reason the its not passing the data it shows nothing in console too

Please note: i also tried removing "window.addEventListener('load', function()" to see if that is whats causing the problem but removing it made no progress its still the same, could some one please tell me whats stopping the script from getting executed

```js
function myfunction() {
  var checkedName = document.querySelector('input[name="case-type"]:checked'),
    checkedType = document.querySelector('input[name="state-name"]:checked'),
    name = checkedName ? checkedName.value : "Nothing selected",
    type = checkedType ? checkedType.value : "Nothing selected"
  $.ajax({ // defining the below function as ajax responsive//
    url: 'Type&State', // the function that process the  mapped url name and matching type is going to receive the data//
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      state_name: name,
      case_type: type
    }, // function to get the value from jsp page and send it to mapped class function//
    success: function(response) { // if the backend process is success then the function will run by getting the response as its parameter//
      alert(response.message);
      data = response.data;
      $('.tr').remove();

      if (response.indexOf("school_name") > -1) {

        for (i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
          $("#table").append("<tr class='tr'> <td> " + response.data[i].school_name + " </td> <td> " + response.data[i].school_email);
        }
      } else {
        for (i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
          $("#table").append("<tr class='tr'> <td> " + response.data[i].college_name + " </td> <td> " + response.data[i].college_email);
        }
      }
    },

    error: function(response) {
      alert("unable to pull up any colleges or schools for the selected state");
    }
  });
}


// to remove default checked:
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var checkedNames = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="case-type"]:checked'),
    checkedTypes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="state-name"]:checked');
  for (var i = 0, n = checkedNames.length; i < n; i++) {
    checkedNames[i].checked = false;
  }
  for (var i = 0, n = checkedTypes.length; i < n; i++) {
    checkedTypes[i].checked = false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="case-type" class="ButtonState" id="school" value="-1" />
    <label class="Button" for="school"> school </label>
    <input type="radio" name="case-type" class="ButtonState" id="college" value="-2" />
    <label class="Button" for="college">college</label>

  </div>

  <br> <br>

  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="state-name" class="ButtonState" id=" Ontario " value="1" />
    <label class="Button" for=" Ontario "> Ontario </label>
    <input type="radio" name="state-name" class="ButtonState" checked id=" British Columbia " value="2" />
    <label class="Button" for=" British Columbia "> British Columbia </label>
    <input type="radio" name="state-name" class="ButtonState" id=" Quebec " value="3" />
    <label class="Button" for=" Quebec "> Quebec </label><input type="radio" name="state-name" class="ButtonState" id=" Alberta " value="4" />
    <label class="Button" for=" Alberta "> Alberta </label><input type="radio" name="state-name" class="ButtonState" id=" Nova Scotia " value="5" />
    <label class="Button" for=" Nova Scotia "> Nova Scotia </label><input type="radio" name="state-name" class="ButtonState" id=" Saskatchewan " value="6" />
    <label class="Button" for=" Saskatchewan "> Saskatchewan </label><input type="radio" name="state-name" class="ButtonState" id=" Manitoba " value="7" />
    <label class="Button" for=" Manitoba "> Manitoba </label><input type="radio" name="state-name" class="ButtonState" id=" New Brunswick " value="8" />
    <label class="Button" for=" New Brunswick "> New Brunswick </label><input type="radio" name="state-name" class="ButtonState" id=" New founded land " value="9" />
    <label class="Button" for=" New founded land "> New founded land </label><input type="radio" name="state-name" class="ButtonState" id=" Prince Edward Isand " value="10" />
    <label class="Button" for=" Prince Edward Isand "> Prince Edward Isand </label>
  </div>
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="myfunction()" />
</form>
```

Comment: how about adding an actual URL instead of `url: 'Type&State'`?

Comment: You should append the `Type&State` to the api url, just passing parameters doesn't work

Comment: or maybe a base-url + `data: {type: paramType, state: paramState},`

Comment: Also `checkedName = $('input[name="case-type"]:checked').val() || "Nothing"`

Comment: Also `$(function() {
  $('input[name="case-type"]:checked', 'input[name="state-name"]:checked').prop("checked",false);
});`

Comment: @mplungjan could you please tell me how to modify the code as like you said sir, im somewhat a newbie to jquery and ajax and rest

Comment: Also `var school = response.indexOf("school_name") > -1;
$.each(response.data,function(item) { var name = school?item.school_name:item.college_name, email = school?item.school_email:item.college_email
          $("#table").append("<tr class='tr'><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + email+"</td></tr>");
        })`

Comment: Please press F12. Look in the console for errors. Look in the network tab to see if the response from the server is what you expect

Comment: @mplungjan sir, the console tab shows nothing except the code the run with no exception being thrown or warnings sir

Comment: @mplungjan sir, i will remove the new question sir

Comment: @mplungjan sir, i tried assigning variable this way  as you suggested checkedName = $('input[name="case-type"]:checked').val() || "Nothing but result is the same sir

Comment: and $(function() { $('input[name="case-type"]:checked', 'input[name="state-name"]:checked').prop("checked",false); }); i could not understand if this is variable assigning code or anything else sir, could you please tell me sir where to modify with this code

Comment: See my answer. Also `response.indexOf("school_name") > -1;` is not likely working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by cleaning the code up. Also check the console network tab to see if the server responds with what you expect

```js
$(function() {

  $('input[name="case-type"]:checked', 'input[name="state-name"]:checked').prop("checked", false);

  $("#goBut").on("click", function() {
    var name = $('input[name="state-name"]:checked').val() || "Nothing selected",
      type = $('input[name="case-type"]:checked').val() || "Nothing selected";

    $.ajax({ // defining the below function as ajax responsive//
      url: 'Type&State', // the function that process the  mapped url name and matching type is going to receive the data//
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        state_name: name,
        case_type: type
      }, // function to get the value from jsp page and send it to mapped class function//
      success: function(response) { // if the backend process is success then the function will run by getting the response as its parameter//
        console.log(response.message);
        data = response.data;
        $('#table').empty();
        var school = response.indexOf("school_name") > -1; // this is suspicious
        $.each(response.data, function(item) {
          var name = school ? item.school_name : item.college_name,
            email = school ? item.school_email : item.college_email;
          $("#table").append("<tr class='tr'><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + email + "</td></tr>");
        })

      },

      error: function(response) {
        alert("unable to pull up any colleges or schools for the selected state");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="case-type" class="ButtonState" id="school" value="-1" />
    <label class="Button" for="school"> school </label>
    <input type="radio" name="case-type" class="ButtonState" id="college" value="-2" />
    <label class="Button" for="college">college</label>

  </div>

  <br> <br>

  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="state-name" class="ButtonState" id=" Ontario " value="1" />
    <label class="Button" for=" Ontario "> Ontario </label>
    <input type="radio" name="state-name" class="ButtonState" checked id=" British Columbia " value="2" />
    <label class="Button" for=" British Columbia "> British Columbia </label>
    <input type="radio" name="state-name" class="ButtonState" id=" Quebec " value="3" />
    <label class="Button" for=" Quebec "> Quebec </label><input type="radio" name="state-name" class="ButtonState" id=" Alberta " value="4" />
    <label class="Button" for=" Alberta "> Alberta </label><input type="radio" name="state-name" class="ButtonState" id=" Nova Scotia " value="5" />
    <label class="Button" for=" Nova Scotia "> Nova Scotia </label><input type="radio" name="state-name" class="ButtonState" id=" Saskatchewan " value="6" />
    <label class="Button" for=" Saskatchewan "> Saskatchewan </label><input type="radio" name="state-name" class="ButtonState" id=" Manitoba " value="7" />
    <label class="Button" for=" Manitoba "> Manitoba </label><input type="radio" name="state-name" class="ButtonState" id=" New Brunswick " value="8" />
    <label class="Button" for=" New Brunswick "> New Brunswick </label><input type="radio" name="state-name" class="ButtonState" id=" New founded land " value="9" />
    <label class="Button" for=" New founded land "> New founded land </label><input type="radio" name="state-name" class="ButtonState" id=" Prince Edward Isand " value="10" />
    <label class="Button" for=" Prince Edward Isand "> Prince Edward Isand </label>
  </div>
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="Go" id="goBut" />
</form>
<table>
  <tbody id="table">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: sir!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! thank you sooooo much sir, it worked finally i have been itching my head this weekend full on this sir!!!!!!!!!!! im really out of words to thank you!!! may god bless you, thank you so much sir